# Connectivity Between SQL Server 2012 and Oracle 12c

Tags: sql-server-2012, oracle12c

I want to know is it possible to connect to an Oracle 12c database with SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2 using SSIS to download data?

As per our IT it's not possible and I don't have these servers to test.

Please help.

Comment: http://www.easysoft.com/applications/oracle/database-gateway-dg4odbc.html

Comment: You should be able to connect using SQL Server's Import and Export wizard.